# Installing plugins in Android on-the-fly

Tags: android, plugins, modularity

I'm trying to achieve is a modular Android application with one core and multiple plugins.

The idea is that you download the main core APK and if you need a feature, the application will pull it down from a remote server (perhaps the Android market) and install it as a second non-launchable application (no launcher) and then fire off an intent from that new plugin.

Can the application download and install that APK **without the user having to initiate it** -- if they are both signed with the same key?

The rationale is that there may be two (or more) teams developing code for the same application onshore and offshore and no code will be shared between them, only interfaces.

Our capacity is already at maximum, but the business demands more work and we're not going to hand over the source code.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1):

> Can the application download and install that APK without the user having to initiate it -- if they are both signed with the same key?

That depends on what you mean by "initiate". You can download the APK yourself. You can fire the `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` with the right MIME type to bring up the installer. The user then has to step through the installer to confirm the installation, approve requested permissions, etc.

> install it as a second non-launchable application (no launcher)

This may not work. On Android 3.1+, applications are initially installed in a "stopped" state. Notably, no `BroadcastReceviers` will work until the user manually launches an activity for the newly-installed app. I do not know if your app will be able to start up an activity (or service) of the other app if the user has not manually launched something from that app. I haven't tried this scenario.

IMHO, your "offshore" folk should be writing Android library projects, which you then integrate into your app.